# How to add SSL to WordPress website into Digital-ocean Apache Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wordpress, ssl, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04, namecheap

I am installing my wordpress website into digital-ocean.Its working fine.Now i need to install ssl on my website. My domain and SSL both are bought form Namecheap .Using Apache in Ubuntu 18.04 on digital-ocean . I didn't find any right solution to add ssl into my website. Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to how to install an SSL certificate on Apache. [Install SSL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority)

RapidSSL is the one offered by Namecheap. First install the SSL on to your sever then you'll have to change your htaccess or back end wordpress to force SSL connections.

Comment: thanks your comment but it will expired after 90 days...

Comment: To an SSL that lasts longer I'm afraid your going to have to buy one.